# Retrieve the unique visitors using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve the unique visitors of a website using eloquent to do so but it is retrieving the numbers of times that the only IP that has visited the website.

```
$visitors = Visitors::
        groupBy('ip')
        ->get(array(
            DB::raw('Date(created_at) as 
            DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "x"')
        ));
```

If I happen to do a simple `dd(Visitors::groupBy('ip')->get())` I get the desired of result of only one result beeing returned.

Here is the structure of my table

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('ip', 40);
$table->timestamps();
```

I would like to follow the scheme where we get the number of visitors into the variable `x` because I'm constructing several graphs using always the same `x` to build `x axis` and `y axis`

---

**UPDATE**
I would like to keep the initial schema to be able to use this auxuliary method to construct the `x axis` and `y axis` of the chart:

```
$pageViewsPerDay = $this->pageViewsPerDay();

private function pageViewsPerDay(){
    $visitors = Visitors::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth())
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
        ->get(array(
            DB::raw('Date(created_at) as date'),
            // x = pageViewsPerDay
            DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "x"')
        ));
    $labels = $this->constructLabel($visitors);
    return $labels;
}

private function constructLabel($data){
    $i = 0;
    $len = count($data);
    $xAxis = '[';
    $yAxis = '[';
    foreach ($data as $dateParticipant) {
        // Contrust the x label -> ["2018-12-14", "2018-12-31", "2012-14-21"]
        // Construct y label -> [10, 20, 2]
        $xAxis = $xAxis . '"' . $dateParticipant->date . '"';
        $yAxis = $yAxis . $dateParticipant->x;
        // It means we are not in the last element
        if ($i != $len - 1) {
            $xAxis = $xAxis . ",";
            $yAxis = $yAxis . ",";
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $xAxis = $xAxis . ']';
    $yAxis = $yAxis . ']';

    return [
        'xAxis' => $xAxis,
        'yAxis' => $yAxis
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$visitors = Visitors::all()->unique('ip');` will return all `Visitors` first, then it will reduce the `Collection` and return only `unique` results based on `ip` field.

**EDIT**

```
$visitors = DB::table('XXXXXX')->distinct('ip')->select('created_at as date', DB::raw('count(*) as x'));
```

Just change `XXXXX` with the table name

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I would like to keep the initial structure to be able to use the auxiliary method that I have after to build the charts

Comment: Can you include it into your question?

Comment: Updated the question to include it

Comment: What is the `$data` variable you are using in the function that creates your chart? Can you include the full code please

Comment: Updated with full example

Comment: Can you verify again that this code doesn't retrieve unique visitors? `$visitors = Visitors::groupBy("ip")->get([DB::raw("Date(created_at) as  'date'"), DB::raw("COUNT(*) as 'x'")]);`

Comment: It returns `"x" => 43 ... "date" => "2018-02-10"` which is not what I'm expecting. I was expecting the unique IP's and not the count of the occurence of all the IPs

Answer (score 1):

what about using [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-unique) helper

```
Visitors::all()->unique('ip');
```

**EDIT:**

```
$visitors = DB::table('XXXXXX')->distinct('ip')->select('created_at as date', DB::raw('count(*) as x'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I would like to keep the initial structure to be able to use the auxiliary method that I have after to build the charts

Comment: Don't use `Visitors::all()` as long as you're sure the table will not be very big. This loads all table rows into PHP. Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

This is more like a SQL Problem in your example. Using an aggregate function in MySQL leads to only one result (row).

If you, in same query, want also to receive the count of visits of a specific IP, then you need to join somehow. The "Eloquent way" can look like:

In your `Visitors` Model include a relation like:

```
public function visitsWithIp() {
    return $this->hasMany(Visitors::class, 'ip', 'ip');
}
```

and with this you can do an eloquent query like:

```
$visitors = Visitors::groupBy('ip')
    ->withCount('visitsWithIp')
    ->get('ip', 'created_at', 'count_visitsWithIp');
```

I did not test the code above, but I'm sure you get the idea behind it ;)

[Details about casting your date between MySQL and PHP](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

[Details about counting eloquent relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)